# How to remove attribute of a tag in Telegram's instant view API?

Tags: api, xpath, xquery, telegram

I have this

```
<span class="img-fc">
  <img src="https://img1.ibxk.com.br/2017/04/12/12095959053024.png?w=700">
  <span class="desc">The image desc is here!</span>
</span>
```

So I used some functions of the API to change the description

```
<figure>: //span[@class="img-fc"]
<figcaption>: //figure[@class="img-fc"]/span[@class="desc"]
```

And I get this result in the instant view debug:

```
> @debug: $body//figure
Debug 1 node:
  [0]: <figure class="img-fc"><img src="https://img1.ibxk.com.br/2017/04/12/12095959053024.png?w=700"><figcaption class="desc">The image desc is here!</figcaption></figure>
Instant View successfully generated
```

But, its not generatig an img with a caption bellow the image. 
Here is the result:
[image: print]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step: convert all `<span class="desc">` tag in `<span class="img-fc">` tag to `<figcaption>` tag:

```
<figcaption>: //span[has-class("img-fc")]//span[has-class("desc")]
```

Second and final step is convert all `<span class="img-fc">` tags to `<figure>`:

```
<figure>: //span[has-class("img-fc")]
```

Comment: Some explanation to your code snippet would be really nice.